# C# ItemsSource for ComboBox with inheritance

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, combobox, itemssource

I've got a `List<T>` like:

```
List<Person> personList;
```

In this list are objects that inherit from Person: `Staff` and `Manager`.

I have a ComboBox `cmbList`.

Now I would like to set the source of this ComboBox to the `Staff` objects from the `personList`.

How can I create a view, so that it looks like two `List`s?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. Do you want two comboboxes? Do you want some code that will get just the `Staff` objects from the `personList`?

Comment: I want one combobox. I want to use itemsSource, but only for one kind of objects (Staff). I know a method, but then I need to set the items every time new...
I now seperated the List in two Lists and just used itemsSource

Answer (score 0):

you can use a ICollectionView to filter your PersonList for Staff Objects and bind this view to your Combobox